# Ubuntu 16.04 check disk for defects

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, usb

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 to a usb stick via win32DiskImager. I can boot from the usb stick but if i try to install Ubuntu on my machine it gets stuck after the ubuntu logo and the screen just turns black and nothing happens. If i run "check disk for defects" it returns 1 error in one file. Why is that? I also tried to get the .iso file via rufus on my usb stick, with same results.

Comment: more information please

Comment: My Hardware: AMD A4-3400, 4GB RAM, MSI A75-MA P35. What else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

One bad file in that check means either that the download was bad (probably this is the reason) or that the pendrive is bad (possible but not likely). I have used Win32DiskImager, and considering the way it works, I think it is very reliable.

So I suggest that you check the ***md5sum*** versus the value at [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes), and download the iso file again, and check the md5sum once more. If you can use the ***torrent*** method, chances are better to succeed, because the checksum is tested during the torrent process.

See the following link for more details: [Win32DiskImager/iso2usb](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb) for several steps in the process including how to check the md5sum in Windows.

-o-

***Edit:***

It is also possible that the iso file itself is bad. Anyway, you should not use the version 16.04 LTS now. You should ***use the version 16.04.1 LTS***, the first point release, which is debugged and polished and much improved.

Comment: I downloaded ubuntu 14.04.4, the generated md5 hash is the same as here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS
But i still get 1 error in 1 file and the screen turns also black after the ubuntu boot logo

Comment: It is strange that you get that error also with another version of Ubuntu. It seems something is not working correctly in the computer at a fundamental level. Please tell us the name of the failing file (if you get that output). Can you try these boot drives in another computer? Just to tell if the problem is with the computer or with the USB boot drive (and the operating system).

Comment: Maybe you should try to clone the iso file into the USB drive in another computer or try another USB drive.

Comment: Or is the USB drive too small for the iso file? It should be at least 2 GB.

Comment: I copied the 14.04.4 iso via rufus to another usb stick (san disk 32gb extreme usb 3.0) and the system didn't find any errors in "check disk for defects" but nevertheless i still get the black screen after i select "install  ubuntu"

Comment: You have solved one problem. So let us focus on the next one. The black screen is probably a problem with the graphics driver. The first tip is that you try with the boot option nomodeset. See this link and links from it, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: Somehow i get to open a terminal while boot process and i see some error messages:
radeon 0000:00:01.0 ring 0 stalled for more than 1000msec
radeon *ERROR* radon: fence wait failed(-35)
radion: failed testing IB on GFX ring(-35)

I tried to replace quiet splash with nomodeset in grub menu but this didn't help anything

Comment: I use graphics from intel and nvidia, but have not much experience of radeon. Many other people know about it. I think those who know and can help you might not look here (with this title), so it is probably better to ask a new question or search among already answered questions about radeon graphics, and your particular model.

Comment: Okay, i added the flag "nomodeset" in the grub boot menu (like it is described here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184839&page=2&p=12871710#post12871710). With that option i was able to boot the live linux, i also managed to install ubuntu via the desktop icon. Until i reboot everything worked fine but the screen turned black again while rebooting. How can i make ubuntu to remember the nomodeset-option?

Comment: It is described in the following link and links from it (edit /etc/default/grub and run sudo update-grub), http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: Should i change grub in live-linux mode or while booting?

Comment: okay, i edited the file in live mode (changed: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset") and i also updated grub (and installed grub before), but i still reboot into a black screen! That's so annoying i thought Ubuntu is user friendly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49175/discussion-between-binarybigint-and-sudodus).